# Get Python ID as a number for Py03 PyAny object in Rust

Tags: python, rust, pyo3

I'm using Py03 to build a python module in Rust. I have a class in Rust which accepts a `PyAny` to refer to an object in Python. As part of the hash function for the rust class, I want to use the Python ID for this object in the hash function in Rust so I can deduplicate the rust class if the same Python object is referenced in multiple versions of the Rust class. I can see the python ID in the `PyAny` object in Rust, but can't figure out how to get it into a plain number that I can pass to the hasher.

For example, I have the following in Rust:

```rust
#[pyclass]
pub struct MyClass {
    obj: Option<Py<PyAny>>,
}
#[pymethods]
impl MyClass {
    #[new]
    fn new(obj: Option<Py<PyAny>>) -> Self {
        if obj.is_some() {
            println!("Obj: {:?}", obj.as_ref());
        }
        Self { obj }
    }
}
```

Then, I can run in Python:

```py
obj = [1,2,3,4]
print(hex(id(obj)))
# '0x103da9100'
MyClass(obj)
# Obj: Some(Py(0x103da9100))
```

Both Python and Rust are showing the same number for the ID, which is great, but how can I get this number `0x103da9100` into a Rust variable? It looks like `PyAny` is just a tuple struct, so I tried the following but Rust complains that the fields of `PyAny` are private:

```rust
let obj_id = obj?.0;
```

Comment: You can get at the contents of the `PyAny` tuple with [`as_ptr`](https://docs.rs/pyo3/0.17.3/pyo3/conversion/trait.AsPyPointer.html#tymethod.as_ptr), but I'm not sure how to get the id from there (unless the id is simply the value of the pointer).

Comment: It looks like you can just cast `as_ptr()` to `isize` or `usize` and it works. Another relevant thread on the Py03 Github page: https://github.com/PyO3/pyo3/discussions/2878

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`obj` in your code is of type `Option<Py<PyAny>>`. To get the underlaying FFI pointer(in your case it's list) you need to de-structure your option first. And then use `destructured_object.as_ptr()` to get `T` from `Py<T>`.

```
#[pymethods]
impl MyClass {
    #[new]
    fn new(obj: Option<Py<PyAny>>) -> Self {
        if let Some(ref obj1) = obj { // obj1 will be of type `Py<PyList> in case of List`
            let concreate_type = obj1.as_ptr(); // Get PyList from `Py<PyList>
            println!("{}", concreate_type as isize)

        }

        Self { obj }
    }
}
```

Now you have the raw pointer in `concreate_type` and you can cast the pointer type to `isize` to get the memory location of an object. That's exactly what Cpython returns as part of the implementation. see `id.__doc__` for more details.

```
>>> print(id.__doc__)
Return the identity of an object.

This is guaranteed to be unique among simultaneously existing objects.
(CPython uses the object's memory address.)
>>> 
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> id(a)
4357355968
>>> 
>>> from myid import MyClass
>>> MyClass(a)
4357355968
```